# Text Wrap Laravel pulling article From DB

Tags: html, css, image, text, word-wrap

I'm using Laravel, pulling an article from a DB and displaying it with an image, it's all lorem ipsum generated.

**Question**: How do I get the article to wrap around the image and beneath it.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

```
@extends('layouts.main')

    @section('headContent')

<div class="container" class="">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">

            <a href="{{ URL::route('equipment-item') }} " alt="{{$fd->name }}"><h2 class="page-header">{{$fd->name }}</h2></a>
            <small>Created: {{ $fd->created_at }}</small>
            <img src="{{ $fd->image }}" alt="{{$fd->name }}">
            </div>

        <div class="col-md-12">
//if i go <div class="col-md-6" (the other 50% of first div) it acts like a side bar. 
            <article class="DBArticle">

                {{ Markdown::parse($fd->description) }}

            </article>
            <a href="{{ URL::route('equipment') }}">Equipment &raquo; </a>
        </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@stop

//CSS --> Using Bootstrap, no other styles.
```

I feel like it's not possible with the way this is set up, but I've been known to be wrong (:

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related Laravel & php. You will get a much better response if you just post the resultant HTML and your CSS.

Comment: I redid my answer to give you an psuedo example that works I am currently using this on my website I am building.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the article in the same tag as the img. Not its own.

Here is how it will go

```
<div>
    <div style="float:left;">
       <img src="your image here" />
    </div>
    your article text
</div>
```

Comment: I get voted down for posting the fix for it...? If it is for the psuedo it is cause copy and pasting the html in there even is '' marks still formats the HTML and doesn't show it. Apprently if I type it in it works but not copied in weird.